# Dynamically change select index value with javascript on Ember

Tags: javascript, jquery, ember.js

So, I was struggling with this problem for a few hours and there is nothing on Google about it, so I'll post the answer just for the sake of SEO for lazy people like me who want to search for this problem and find the solution straightaway.
If you are building a bookmarklet to fill a big form for you, usually when you have to change things and test it multiple times, or building some kind of automated feature test which fill forms and submit it, just changing the `selectedIndex` with javascript won't pass the selected option to Ember, because you need to actually trigger the `change` event, so imagining you have this setup:

```
<select id='test'>
    <option value="1">First Option</option>
    <option value="2">Second Option</option>
</select>
```

and you want to select and option via javascript and submit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Doing just

```
document.getElementById('test').selectedIndex = 1;
```

won't work, you need to do:

```
document.getElementById('test').selectedIndex = 1;
$('#test').trigger('change');
```

since Ember takes the value of the selected option on a change event, which is not triggered when you just set the option dynamically. Now this seems pretty obvious for some people, but it may not be for others.

Comment: If you knew the answer..Why  you need to ask the question ??

Comment: Answering your own question is encouraged - https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17463/can-i-answer-my-own-questions-even-if-i-knew-the-answer-before-asking

Comment: Thank you for posting and answering this.  I spent forever on google before I landed on your answer.